# How to start hadoop without asking local machine password?

Tags: hadoop, access-rights

```
amtex@amtex-desktop:~$ start-all.sh
```

This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]

amtex@localhost's password: 
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /home/amtex/Documents/installed/hadoop/logs/hadoop-amtex-namenode-amtex-desktop.out

```
amtex@localhost's password:
```

localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/amtex/Documents/installed/hadoop/logs/hadoop-amtex-datanode-amtex-desktop.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]

```
amtex@0.0.0.0's password:
```

0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/amtex/Documents/installed/hadoop/logs/hadoop-amtex-secondarynamenode-amtex-desktop.out
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /home/amtex/Documents/installed/hadoop/logs/yarn-amtex-resourcemanager-amtex-desktop.out

```
amtex@localhost's password:
```

localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /home/amtex/Documents/installed/hadoop/logs/yarn-amtex-nodemanager-amtex-desktop.out

```
amtex@amtex-desktop:~$ jps
2404 Startup
18244 DataNode
18580 ResourceManager
18101 NameNode
18889 NodeManager
18425 SecondaryNameNode
18924 Jps
```

Comment: Based on my research i follow these steps to avoid the above problem **stop1:** `ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""` **stop2:** `cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hadoop: require root's password after enter "start-all.sh"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195048/hadoop-require-roots-password-after-enter-start-all-sh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my research i follow these steps to avoid the above problem

**step 1:** `ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""`

**step 2:** `cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`

and now i started hadoop

```
amtex@amtex-desktop:~$ start-all.sh

This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /home/amtex/Documents/installed/hadoop/logs/hadoop-amtex-namenode-amtex-desktop.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/amtex/Documents/installed/hadoop/logs/hadoop-amtex-datanode-amtex-desktop.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/amtex/Documents/installed/hadoop/logs/hadoop-amtex-secondarynamenode-amtex-desktop.out
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /home/amtex/Documents/installed/hadoop/logs/yarn-amtex-resourcemanager-amtex-desktop.out
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /home/amtex/Documents/installed/hadoop/logs/yarn-amtex-nodemanager-amtex-desktop.out
amtex@amtex-desktop:~$ start-master.sh
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /home/amtex/Documents/installed/spark/logs/spark-amtex-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-amtex-desktop.out
amtex@amtex-desktop:~$ start-slaves.sh
localhost: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /home/amtex/Documents/installed/spark/logs/spark-amtex-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-amtex-desktop.out

amtex@amtex-desktop:~$ jps

21523 Jps
2404 Startup
21029 NodeManager
20581 DataNode
20439 NameNode
20760 SecondaryNameNode
21353 Master
21466 Worker
20911 ResourceManager
```

Answer (score 1):

You need set password less login between machine

Below link has the step by step procedure to setup ssh password less login

http://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/

Hope this helps!!!...