# Launching apache spark without root access

Tags: apache-spark, ssh

I am trying to set up a spark cluster on multiple servers using VMWare to configure them. However I have not been given root privileges for the servers. (I understand it should be possible to set up a spark cluster without root access) When I try to launch spark using `sbin/start-all.sh` it requests a root password to start the slave. I have already tried generating ssh keys and copying them to the servers, using the method explained in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login), however, it still request root password when I attempt to launch slave. Does anyone know a workaround this?

Comment: try  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195048/hadoop-require-roots-password-after-enter-start-all-sh

Comment: I have tried that as well. I can ssh into the servers without a password which means the ssh keys should be configured correctly. However, when I launch spark, it still requests root@user password..

Comment: Can you also ssh as root@machine without a password? Or just as the currently logged in user?